# If $A$ is a rotation matrix by $\theta$, then what does $A^T$ do?

Tags: matrices, rotations, angle

Little help here?

If multiplication by $A$ rotates a vector $x$ in the $x$-$y$ plane through an angle $\theta$, then what is the effect of multiplying $x$ by $A^T$. Explain your reasoning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted anything so far?

Comment: I think if you try a few vectors it should be easy to see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

What is the matrix that represents rotation in the xy-plane by angle $\theta$ *counterclockwise*?

(Googling it or searching MSE will surely get you the matrix, but even better would be for you to try to compute it from scratch, which requires just a bit more thought...)

Now, what is the transpose of this matrix?

Finally, take **simple** basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$; what does the transpose of the original rotation matrix do to these vectors?

Key point is this:  knowing the action of your linear operator (or matrix, with respect to some chosen basis) on basis vectors completely determines the action of the linear operator on *all* vectors in the vector space, i.e., in the two-dimensional $x$-$y$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- A rotation is an orthogonal transformation.
- An orthogonal matrix $M$ has $M^t=M^{-1}$.